# "IndexError: list index out of range" when trying to solve Python for Everybody Exercise 10.2

Tags: python

I started Python for Everybody course recently and I am currently stuck on Exercise 10.2. The exact error message I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tinyp\Desktop\py4e\new.py", line 10, in <module> 
    words = words[5].split(":")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Could someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

The prompt is as follows:

> 10.2 Write a program to read through the mbox-short.txt and figure out the distribution by hour of the day for each of the messages. You can
> pull the hour out from the 'From ' line by finding the time and then
> splitting the string a second time using a colon. **SAMPLE TEXT:** `From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008` Once you have
> accumulated the counts for each hour, print out the counts, sorted by
> hour as shown below.

Below is what I have so far:

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1:
    name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
counts = dict()
for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith("From"):
        continue
    words = line.split()
    words = words[5].split(":")  # <-- this is the line that keeps giving me the error message
    words = words[0]
    for word in words:
        counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1
lst = list()
for key, value in counts.items():
    lst.append((value, key))
lst = sorted(lst, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Hi! Are you asking what the input file looks like? Sorry, I'm super new to all this. This is a sample line from the text file: From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008.

Comment: `list index out of range` means that length (number of elements) of `words` (after splitting) is less than 6 and `words[5]` can't be used. You have to add check like `if len(words) >= 6:`

Comment: @rzlvmp Thank you so much for your response! So here is the sample line given in the prmopt: From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008. If I split it, wouldn't the length be 6 and words[5] be 09:14:16? Am I counting wrong or misunderstanding the concept of splitting/splicing?

Comment: What's the error message? Provide the full error traceback. Also, provide a sample text file.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark Hi there! Sample text file is this: From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008. The error message I am getting is: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\tinyp\Desktop\py4e\new.py", line 10, in <module>
words = words[5].split(":")
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Please provide this information in an edit to your post.

Comment: Did you have anymore sample lines? Or a parts of the text file. It’s hard to help without knowing more information as it is not this case that is the issue.

Comment: @Chris Hey! Please accept my apologies, I really wasn't sure what would be useful information to include. The entirety of the sample text can be found here: https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt. Is this helpful to have?

Comment: @Sae `The entirety of the sample text can be found here` → 38th line.

Comment: Beside the point, but reusing the variable name "words" seems to be a mistake. I think you want `time = words[5].split(":"); hour = time[0]`. And then why are you doing `for word in words`? Shouldn't it be `counts[hour] = counts.get(hour, 0) + 1`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including example data that reproduces the problem **in the question itself**. As rzlvmp pointed out, this example data doesn't reproduce the problem, only the data you linked in a comment. BTW, if you want more tips, see [ask].

Comment: @wjandrea Hey! Thank you so much for taking the time to share the links and also for editing my post. It looks like I have a ton of learning to do just to be able to post an intelligible question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let me help you.

1. You said

   > SAMPLE TEXT: From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008

   It is not. I simply change your code:

   ```py
   handle = ["From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008",]

   counts = dict()
   for line in handle:
       line = line.rstrip()
       if not line.startswith("From"): continue
       words = line.split()
       words = words[5].split(":")
       words = words[0]
       for word in words:
           counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1
   lst = list()
   for key, value in counts.items():
       lst.append((value, key))
   lst = sorted(lst, reverse=True)
   ```

   And it is working without any problem. That means that you have another `From`s in your text file.
2. What you have to do → If you don't understand why `words` cause error, **just print it!**. Genially simple.

   In other words change your

   ```py
   words = words[5].split(":")
   ```

   to

   ```py
   try:
       words = words[5].split(":")
   except IndexError:
       print('Okay! that is our error. Gotcha')
       print('words is', words)
   ```

easy

Answer (score 0):

What has happened is you have another “From” at the start of a line in the text file.

By adding a check to make sure that each line has at least 6 parts, you won’t exceed the length of each array.

```py
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1:
    name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
counts = dict()
for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith("From"): continue
    words = line.split()
    if len(words) < 6: continue
    words = words[5].split(":")
    words = words[0]
    for word in words:
        counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1
lst = list()
for key, value in counts.items():
    lst.append((value, key))
lst = sorted(lst, reverse=True)
```